# Jenkins build strategy with a PHP project from Git

Tags: php, git, jenkins

I have Jenkins set up on a remote server which hosts my PHP project. Jenkins creates a build from a git repository and I would like then to move the files to the servers document root.

However the problem is all the files have the Jenkins user as their owner. So if I moved the workspace to my document root I wouldn't have permission to access them.

I'm wondering what people do to automate this? Maybe execute shell commands after the build is completed? I'm very new to Jenkins so I may be on the completely wrong track.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer would be yes, you need a post-build step that runs `chown` (change ownership) and/or `chmod` (change permissions) linux commands. This will allow you to switch owning user (if jenkins user has enough rights for it) and set read/write permissions for files up to 777 (free-for-all).

However, it's more than that. You've stumbled upon *deployment* phase of project, and it's much more complex than that. Usually that's handled by external tools called via bash (i'm not very familiar with those, but i certainly know capistrano is an industry standard in ruby), and those tools *usually* (every project may require special scenario) update project files, update dependencies, deploy migrations to database, manage permissions, clean cache, etc., etc.